# How to convert .plist xml string to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsdata

I downloaded `.plist` file with `Swift` and `Alamofire` and I want to read values of .plist file.

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    Alamofire.download(url).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            if let plistData = response.result.value {
                if let plistXml = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    // plistXml contains the actual plist contents as String object.
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

I have to objects containing my downloaded .plist file:

- plistData: the downloaded Data object
- plistXml: String object from plistData

Using any of these objects, I want to convert the plist fie to NSDictionary or Dictionary.

Comment: See Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html

Comment: @UlasSancak It is not using Swift :(

Comment: @malhobayyeb: (NS)PropertyListSerialization is from the Foundation framework and is available in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR I tried `PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(...)` but it does not return `NSDictionary`

Comment: have you tried NSDictionary(contentsOf: URL>)

Comment: @zombie: That would be a *synchronous* request, so that you must take care not to block the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/propertylistserialization) from the Foundation framework to create a `NSDictionary`
from the given property list data. Swift 3 Example:

```
do {
    if let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, format: nil)
        as? NSDictionary  {
            // Successfully read property list.
            print(plist)

    } else {
        print("not a dictionary")
    }
} catch let error {
    print("not a plist:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And with

```
    if let plist = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, format: nil)
        as? [String: Any]  { ... }
```

you'll get the result as a Swift `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash)
2. Read plistXml and parse xml step by step using that documentation.
3. Save the element that you want to inside plistXml into Dictionary

Good Luck!

Comment: I would use `XMLParser` instead. However, it is first time I heard of this. I will check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the objective-C version of code. You can convert it very easily.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"register.plist"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"register" ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: I am downloading the `.plist` file from a url. I can get it as either a `Data` object or as a `String` object. So I want to convert it from `String` or `Data` to `Dictionary` or NSDictionary`

Comment: Use this to convert NSData into NSDictionary->

NSError *errorJson=nil;
            NSDictionary* dictionaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];