# Check existence of localized string in .strings resource file, fall back to default

Tags: swift, foundation, nsbundle, nslocalizedstring

I want to find the appropriate localized string based on some runtime variable and fall back to a default string:

```
// localizable.strings
"com.myapp.text1"         = "The default text 1";
"com.myapp.text1#SPECIAL" = "The special text";
"com.myapp.text2"         = "The default text 2";
```

```
// my code

let key1     = "com.myapp.text1"
let key2     = "com.myapp.text2"
let modifier = "#SPECIAL"
print( NSLocalizedString(key1 + modifier
                        , value:  NSLocalizedString(key1, comment: "")
                        , comment: "") )
// > "The special text 1"
print( NSLocalizedString(key2 + modifier
                        , value: NSLocalizedString(key2, comment: "") # the default to fall back to
                        , comment: "") )
// > "The default text 2"
```

Nice, that's what I want, try a special variant, fall back to the default.

However, if the option `NSShowNonLocalizedStrings` in the user defaults is set to `true`, it fails:
For non-localised strings, an upper-case version of the key will be returned, ignoring the default value. Also an error message is printed in the console ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1417694-localizedstringforkey)).
So it appears that my solution is working against intended way of using NSLocalizedString.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSShowNonLocalizedStrings") # could also be passed as launch option or set via terminal
print( NSLocalizedString(key2 + modifier
                        , value: NSLocalizedString(key2, comment: "")
                        , comment: "") )
// > ERROR: com.myapp.text2#MODIFIER not found [...]
// > "COM.MYAPP.TEXT2"
```

I could work around this by testing for the uppercased version etc. but this would just be a hack that masks the actual issue.
What I would probably need is a test `if (bundle.hasLocalizationFor(key2 + modifier)...` but to implement such a method I would have to re-implement processing of the strings files including parsing and caching. And that feels wrong in itself.

**Question:**

Is there some method I am missing to achieve what I am looking for?
Or is the whole idea of special/fallback localization just wrong for the platform?

Comment: Strings files are property lists, and reading those is not difficult (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013256/1187415). But the very purpose of NSShowNonLocalizedStrings is to detect non-existing keys, so I would probably add a new key (combination) whenever necessary.

Comment: "Strings files are property lists" – awesome, I wasn't aware! So the parsing part is solved for free. Ok, now I can throw in some caching. It still feels like a hack though.

Comment: Fwiw, I found that this is documented at the bottom of this file:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html

Comment: You could also write a helper function which calls NSLocalizedString and compares the return value against the uppercased key, and in that case returns the default value. But that still leaves you with the error messages.

Comment: yes – I considered that. But littering error messages all over the project is not an option.

Comment: Sure. I still think that defining translations for all possible key combinations is the better option. – Btw, wouldn't your example `NSLocalizedString(key2 + modifier, value: key2, comment: "")` with NSShowNonLocalizedStrings=false return "com.myapp.text2" and not "The default text 2", as you said?

Comment: Right, I oversimplified, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments by Martin R, I was able to get a reasonably working solution:

```
static let cache = NSCache<NSString, NSDictionary>()
private func strings(for tableName: String) -> [String: String] {

    guard let strings = cache.object(forKey: tableName as NSString) else {

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: tableName, ofType: "strings")
            , let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] else {

                return [:]
        }
        cache.setObject(dict as NSDictionary, forKey: tableName as NSString)
        return dict
    }
    return strings as! [String: String]
}

func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
    let specificKey = key + "#SPECIAL"
    let tableName = "TableName"
    let bundle = Bundle.main

    return self.strings(for: tableName)[specificKey]
    ?? NSLocalizedString(key
                         , tableName: tableName
                         , bundle: bundle
                         , comment: "")
}
```